# Rules for constructing a matrix B which has the same eigenvalues and eigenvectors as another matrix A?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a square matrix $A$, for which I know the eigenvectors and eigenvalues. I want to build a new matrix $B$ (possibly blockwise) which has exactly the same eigenvectors and eigenvalues as $A$ (in which the eigenvalues are mostly positive real numbers, but might have one or two negative real values scattered in there too). 
What rules or algorithm do I need to follow in the construction of $B$ to ensure it conforms to the requirement above? Is there an algebraic or iterative process that needs to be followed, or do I have to resort to something messy like a genetic algorithm, using 'closeness to $A$'s eigenproperties' fitness function?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you know a basis of eigenvectors of $A$.

Write the eigenvectors of $A$ into a matrix $S$. Then it holds
$$
AS= SD,
$$
where $D$ is diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $A$ on the diagonal.

Now permute the elements on the diagonal of $D$ to get a diagonal matrix $\tilde D$. Set
$$
B:=S\tilde D S^{-1}.
$$
Then $B$ has the same eigenvectors and eigenvalues as $A$. Possibly the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ for one particular eigenvector may be different.

---

This technique can be extended to arbitrary complex matrices using the Jordan form, $AS=SJ$, where $J$ is in Jordan form. Then one can exchange Jordan blocks of the same size in $J$ to obtain $\tilde J$. Then setting $B=S^{-1}\tilde J S$ has the same eigenvalues and eigenvectors as $A$ (and not more).

Comment: Thanks! So are you saying that the only freedom that exists in the construction of $B$ lies in how you permute the elements on the diagonal of $D$ ?

Comment: The one loophole is if the eigenvectors don't form a basis for the space.  For example, the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ has only one eigenvector.  In this case, $S$ is not a square matrix and $S^{-1}$ can't be formed. (More accurately, you have to distinguish between the left inverse and the right inverse, and the resulting $B$ will not necessarily have the same dimensions as $A$.)

Comment: If I soften the requirements so that the eigenvectors of $B$ only have to be collinear with those of $A$ (i.e. they have the same normalized eigenvectors), I don't suppose that gains any extra freedom, does it?

Comment: @srk : No.  If $\vec{v}$ is an eigenvector, then so is $\lambda \vec{v}$ for all $\lambda$.  In the procedure above, you are effectively replacing $S$ by $S T$, where $T$ is a diagonal matrix;  and it's not hard to show that this results in exactly the same $B$.  (Use the fact that any two diagonal matrices commute with each other.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert the trick also works with Jordan form

Comment: Thanks again. @Michael Seifert, your 'loophole' answer is interesting.